# Multiple Linear Regression warning

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to fit a linear model , but I face this warning;

```
> reg=lm(Data.readmitted ~., newdata)

Warning messages:

1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :

`  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored

`2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

and its `str()` from my dataset :

```
> str(newdata)


'data.frame':  94613 obs. of  4 variables:
    $ Data.race      : Factor w/ 5 levels "AfricanAmerican",..: 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
    $ Data.gender    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Female","Male",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
    $ Data.age       : Factor w/ 10 levels "[0-10)","[10-20)",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ..
    $ Data.readmitted: Factor w/ 3 levels "<30",">30","NO": 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 ...
     - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:2153] 20 21 22 55 66 88 100 112 128 178 ...
    .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2153] "20" "21" "22" "55" ...
```

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. If you don't want factors, use `as.numeric()` on your data or `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you import your data.

Comment: lm is the wrong type of model for a categorical dependent variable. Thus, it can't handle it properly.

Comment: so , what can I do ?

Comment: My go to resource is google: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/220675_90da5cd7a01c4a57b9f22ff2b89bc915.html